Supporting multiple environments/instances on GKE/Istio for a NextJS Web App
Deployment Setup

GKE Cluster with Istio Service Mesh on GCP
Spring Boot based APIs running on the GKE cluster.
NextJS Web App (Mostly CSR with some SSR)

ASK:
We are wanting to support having multiple environments say for DEV1, 2, Hotfixes etc especially for the Web app.
To do this, I am wanting to use Istio to route requests to the correct namespace/workload based on either a header/cookie.
However, the challenge we are facing is the ability to add a header or a cookie to the first request so that Istio understands where to route the request.
Being new to the Web development, I am unsure on how to achieve this - Assitance appreciated.
One more constraint that we have is that we cannot change the paths or domain as we are behind a bot protection system and changing paths every so often is difficult.
We tried using the NextJS headers(), using a middleware to add request headers and adding headers/cookies in the _app.tsx in a useEffect() hook, but all of them are too late for the first request for the landing page.
